# k.$gen is not a function in Google-cloud BigQuery

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, export-to-csv

I try to upload a csv file as a table to Google BigQuery

[image]

and get the following error:

[image]

How can I solve this? tried to uncheck the "auto detect" but it didn'

Comment: do you have a sample file with very few rows we could use to replicate the issue? Looking at the error, seems like an issue on the import of BQ.

Comment: Hello, a sample of data would be useful indeed. On my side I have tested to load a CSV document with just one row (the one marked in red in your screenshot) and I was able to upload the file into a table and perform queries. Could you please check if the data is properly exported into CSV format? Can you provide us a few lines in text format of the CSV?

Comment: Without a strange CSV format, the errors makes no sense!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate this on my test project but did not encounter the error. This could be a possible bug. [1](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) Just select Create new BigQuery issue for your case.

As an alternative, I recommend you to use bq commands [2](http://%5B2%5D%20https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-command-line#createtable) [3](http://%5B3%5D%20https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table) to try to load your table. These commands can be executed via the GCP console. You can access the table you want to load in your storage buckets as well. [4](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets)

```
$ bq load \
--autodetect=true \
--source_format=CSV \
[datasetID].[tableID] \
[input file]
```